# Set up Eclipse with Android SDK fails

Tags: android, eclipse

I installed latest Eclipse EE Juno, Android SDK tool (for existing IDE) and set up the ADT Bundle via Eclipse.
Now everytime I start Eclipse I get several pop up and console errors:

> Error when loading the SDK: Error: Missing platform-tools

I tried to execute the Android SDK Manager via Eclipse, cmd and file system.
Eclipse console says:

> [SDK Manager] Der Befehl "C:\Program" ist entweder falsch geschrieben
>
> [SDK Manager] oder  konnte nicht gefunden werden.
>
> [SDK Manager] Ung�ltiger Pfad
>
> [SDK Manager] Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.

The SDK Manager is not in `C:\Program` but `C:\Android` and I set the PATH-variable.
In the preferences of Eclipse I have set the correct path to the android files but after applying no SDK targets are displayed.

Somewhere I found that Windows Firewall is blocking the tools sometimes so I deactivated Windows Firewall and ran all programs as admin.

Restarting of eclipse doesn't make this better.
Please help me- I am on the verge of despair....

Comment: have you tried executing Exlipse with administrator priviliges?

Answer (score 0):

Actually , ***ECLIPSE Kepler*** is the latest version. 
Well, this sort of trouble occured to me **when i had formatted my PC and tried adding SDK in Eclipse again.**
Somehow it started working but, SDK was never able to update itself. I couldn't find much solution for that issue.

A less arduous solution would be **to download the Brand new SDK all over**, if it's not too much trouble.
**Otherwise you can download multiple versions of ECLIPSE and try with existing one**.
Actually I am a Trainee Android Developer, so can suggest only these ways.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using another flavor of Eclipse, then I recommend you use [the one that comes with the SDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/index.html). It saves you the trouble of configuring Android in Eclipse.